# Javascript code Substring

Tags: javascript, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm trying to create a gadget for win 7, that retrieves the RSS feed from a site. So far so good, everything works fine, just that I want to add something extra. The gadget so far extracts the link from the feed and stores it in a variable named 'articlelink', the link is usually something like "http://site.ro/film/2009/brxfcno-/22462" or "http://site.ro/serial/2004/veronica-mars---sez-3/1902".

This variable is used to create a link in the title of the flyout window that appears when the link in the gadget window is pressed.

What I need is a piece of code that extracts the number at the end (22462, 1902) and stores it in another variable so I can create a new link with it, which can be displayed in the flyout window as a separate link.

Example

initial link 
http://site.ro/serial/2004/veronica-mars---sezonul-3/1902

new link 
http://site.ro/get/1902

Comment: Could you please make the title more specific? "Javascript code" is very broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var link = "h*t*t*p://site.ro/serial/2004/veronica-mars---sezonul-3/1902";
var id = link.match(/\d+$/)[0]; // id will contain: 1902
```

Answering Splash's question below:

```
var matches = link.match(/([^/]+)\/(\d+)$/);
var id = matches[2]; // 1902
var title = matches[1]; // veronica-mars---sezonul-3
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to modify the piece of code from above so I can get this part now "veronica-mars---sezonul-3". Maybe someone can help with this.

Regards,
Chris.

Answer (score 4):

An idiom for getting the last part of a string:

```
 var id= link.split('/').pop();
```

Slightly more readable than than CMS's version, at the cost of being somewhat slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract a [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), to get the characters between the last `/` and the end:

```
var id = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // 1902
```